# Save result of stored procedure in a Table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SELECT * INTO [temp table] FROM [stored procedure]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

I have a nested stored procedure call

In one of the stored procedures I want to save the result into a table variable likt this :

```
INSERT INTO @myTable 
EXEC sp_myStoredProcedure
```

however, because the proc. is nested the following error occurs :
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

The procedure must be called from another procedure, changing this is not an option.
I wanted to try to use an output parameter but it still has to be set with a Insert into statement.

What are other options to save the data that is retrieved from the call of a Stored Procedure into a variable ?

Comment: What if you call the stored procedure using `opendatasource`? Often gets around a lot of these types of limitations at the expense of opening up another connection to the SQL Server.

Comment: Please do one thing ,call sp using EXECUTE sp_executesql and set one output parameter .                                      refer link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/262499

Answer (score 3):

Table variables are not visible to the calling procedure in the case of nested procs. The following is legal with #temp tables.

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305977/en-us

Answer (score -3):

Not tested but maybe do this:

```
DECLARE @insertedProc as varchar(300)
SET @insertedProc = 'INSERT INTO ' + @myTable + ' sp_myStoredProcedure'

EXEC @insertedProc
```

Make sure you have defined what @myTable is before hand.

Comment: This will not work, Jan said "I want to save the result into a **table variable** " not a table specified in a variable.